# Differences between old and new Unix compilers?

Tags: c, unix

I was reading "The C programming language by Dennis Ritchie" and in the very beginning
it demonstrates a code i.e the following

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
printf("Hello, World");
}
```

according to the book this code should work just fine. However, when i compile this code it generates an error demanding me to make the main return type specifically "int" type. even making it void gives compiling error. Why is that? Its really bugging me. I thought since the book is authored by the creator of the language it would be accurate, i guess not...

Im running it on Unix FreeBSD 10.0

Comment: It's not inaccurate, it's just massively outdated.  What compiler are you using, and with what settings?

Comment: This is a warning not an error unless you are compiling with `-Werror`

Comment: Im running it on Unix FreeBSD 10.0 via VMware, Sorry thats the most technical im aware of. just a newbie, lot to learn

Comment: and why does it strongly suggests int type? could you please suggest me a book thats good for the concepts for the beginner and also not so outdated..

Comment: It is useful for `main` to return an `int` that tells the end user if the program completed successfully or not. By convention, if the program has an exit status of 0 or `EXIT_SUCCESS` (as defined in `stdlib.h`, I think), then it completed successfully. If the exit status is non-zero or `EXIT_FAILURE`, that usually is a hint that the program failed. One of your jobs as a programmer is to handle error cases and, in cases where the program hits a fatal problem and needs to quit early, have the program return a useful error code to help the end user (and maybe you) figure out what went wrong.

Comment: K&R2 is outdated but you must read it, its not for nothing its called "The C Bible", also take a look to [comp.lang.c Frequently Asked Questions](http://c-faq.com/)

Comment: *Practical C Programming* is okay and covers C with a more modern focus (albeit from the late 1990s): http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923065.do

Comment: That isn't exactly what is in the book, is it?  It is missing at least the newline from the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That book was written decades ago, and the language has moved on quite a bit since then.

Even the edition that covered ANSI C (the predecessor being K&R) is well out of date. It covered C89/90 and we've since had C99 and C11.

There may well be compilers that use the older iteration of the standard (such as for some embedded systems) but that's not the case for the compiler *you're* using, at least with the options you have.

If you want to learn the *current* language,  I suggest you choose a more up-to-date book.

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems a correct answer to me. Just curious.